# How to output php code block in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've been searching for the past hour for an answer to this and I can't seem to find one. I want to output a php or javascript code example to my page so that the user can see example code. However, I can't do this using reactJs and jsx because it causes an error.

So this is an example if the kind of code I want to be seen on the screen.

```
if(isset($_POST['user')){//do something}
```

How can I output this in jsx? Can anyone shed some light on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code with `
like

```
{`if(isset($_POST['user')){//do something}`}
```

Comment: This works, provided that it's wrapped in curly braces.

Comment: The curly brackets is a fairly important part.. Shuja can you add them to your answer for the next person who comes across this post and I will accept it. Thanks to both of ye.